# Obtain function from its partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I should determine the function $M(H,T)$ by only knowing the derivatives:

$$
\left ( \frac{\partial M}{\partial H } \right )_{T}=\frac{a}{1-T/T_c}+3bH^{2}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some real constants

$$
\left ( \frac{\partial M}{\partial T } \right )_{H}=
    \frac{1}{T_{c}}\frac{f(H)}{(1-T/T_c)^{2}}-
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{M_{0}}{T_{c}}\frac{1}{(1-T/T_c)^{1/2}}
$$

with $M_{0}$, $T_{c}$, $a$ and $b$ are constants and $f(H)$ is some function
with the property $f(H=0)=0$. The variable $T$ will be bound to the domain $0\le T\lt T_{c}$.

a) determine $f(H)$

b) determine $M(T,H)$

Now I would start by writing down

$$
dM = \left ( \frac{\partial M}{\partial H } \right )_{T}dH + \left ( \frac{\partial M}{\partial T } \right )_{H} dT
$$

This tells me how I would obtain the M in terms of the derivatives.
I tried now to do the integration what gives:
$$
M(T,H)=\frac{aH}{1-T/T_{c}}+bH^{3}+\frac{f(H)}{1-T/T_{c}}+M_{0}(1-T/T_{c})^{1/2}
$$

If I compute now again the derivative with respect to H I obtain:
$$
\left ( \frac{\partial M}{\partial H } \right )_{T}=\frac{a}{1-T/T_c}+3bH^{2}+\frac{1}{1-T/T_{c}}\frac{\partial f(H)}{\partial H}
$$

This is now not the same as at the beginning. From here I don't know how to go on. Is this already wrong or is it somehow possible from this equation to determine $f(H)$.
My first intuition was to say $f(H)$ is just zero, because then the derivative with respect to $H$ would be satisfied and so would be the $f(H=0)=0$ criterion. But this might also be a trivial solution.

Comment: What's the answer provided?

Comment: @Dhamnekar Winod: I don't have one this is my problem. What I wrote above is everything I got

Comment: I suggest tag your question with "partial differential equations" to have more chances for attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us integrate the first equation with respect to $H$ while $T$ is seen as a constant:
$$
M(T,H) = \frac{a H}{1-T/T_c} + bH^3 + \phi(T)
$$
where $\phi(T)$ is an "integration constant" depending on $T$. Now, the partial derivative w.r.t. $T$ is
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial T} = \frac{a H}{T_c}\frac{1}{(1-T/T_c)^2} + \phi'(T)
$$
where $\phi'$ is the derivative of $\phi$. Therefore, $f(H)=aH$ and
$\phi'(T) = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{M_{0}}{T_{c}}(1-T/T_c)^{-1/2}$. The
integration of this last equation with respect to $T$ gives $\phi(T)$ and introduces an integration constant $C$. Finally, $M$ is defined up to a constant $C$ by
$$
M(T,H) = \frac{a H}{1-T/T_c} + bH^3 + M_0\, (1-T/T_c)^{1/2} + C\, .
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Perform the integrations

$$M(T,H)=\int D_h(T,H)\,dT+C_h(H)=\int D_t(T,H)\,dH+C_t(T))
\\=I_h(T,H)+C_h(H)=I_t(T,H)+C_t(T),$$

and determine the functions $C_h,C_t$ that fit.